# Windows 7 Install Dummy Sound Device

Tags: windows-7, audio, flash

I have been asked to help with a problem involving a Flash Interface.

One of the requirements is a sound device otherwise you cannot select some of the answers in the flash programs.

I have looked for the solution, but everything else revolves around routing audio from an already existing output.

Is there an application, or Windows 7 built in feature that will emulate a sound device.
Capturing the output is unnecessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick google-search and found a few emulation alternatives.

http://e2esoft-vsc.software.informer.com/

As I haven't tried it, I can't really vouch for it - but it might work?

Google Search: https://www.google.no/search?q=software+sound+card+emulator+windows+7&aq=f&oq=software+sound+card+emulator+windows+7&aqs=chrome.0.57.7483j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8